# Unable to obtain CDI 1.1 utilities for Mojarra websphere server

Tags: deployment, websphere

[10/20/21 15:20:38:248 GMT] 0000006e view E   Unable to obtain CDI 1.1 utilities for Mojarra
[10/20/21 15:20:38:254 GMT] 0000006e flow  E   Unable to obtain CDI 1.1 utilities for Mojarra
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:610)
at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:244)
at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:129)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:872)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:607)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:872)

Comment: Which WebSphere and Mojarra versions are you using?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just posting random code or error logs won't help you get an answer. Please consider editing your question.

Comment: Websphere 9 and JSF 2.2

Comment: slf4j logger error trace can be ignored as app stopped before getting that error, so the root cause of the issue is mojarra

Answer (score 1):

One problem here is that WebSphere 9 does not provide CDI integration with third-party JSF implementations like Mojarra. I'm not sure if this message `Unable to obtain CDI 1.1 utilities for Mojarra` error is caused by that lack of integration. IBM provides some docs for [configuring third-party JSF implementations](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/9.0.5?topic=files-configuring-javaserver-faces-22) - for example putting the Mojarra lib in an isolated shared library is recommended.

Regardless CDI ViewScoped beans will not work correctly in this configuration. The WebSphere 9 runtime provides JSF MyFaces 2.2, which does have CDI integration. If you do need CDI+JSF integration, you should consider updating your app to use the JSF provided by WebSphere 9.